# How to insert an element into specified index of a 2D array in python

Tags: python, list, append

How to insert an element into specified index of a 2D array in python (note edition : no more context)

```py
N=int(input()) 
A = [] 
for i in range(N): 
    c = [int(x) for x in input().split()][:N] 
    A.append(c) 
A_A = [] 
for j in range(N): 
    for k in range(N): 
        d=0 
        s=((A[j][k])*(A[k][j])) 
        d=s+d 
        print(d) 
        A_A[j][k].append(d) 
        print(A_A)`
```

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: And please explain yhat is wrong with your code, where are you stuck, what did you try, etc ...